# HPE ProLiant gen 10 in legacy boot mode does not see hard drives in boot order section

Tags: boot, grub, legacy

I have HPE ProLiant gen 10 server with 8 drives. If I use legacy boot mode, but there is nothing in legacy boot order setting. And server tries to boot just from the ethernet.

I have installed grub on hard drives and need to boot from them.

Please any idea what to do? Some kind of another bios settings? I am not an expert in hardware/bios setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Embedded SATA Configuration option to enable embedded chipset SATA (Serial Advanced
Technology Attachment) controller support. You can select AHCI or HPE Smart Array S100i SR Gen10 SW RAID support. Make sure that you are using the correct operating system drivers for your selected option.
Dynamic Smart Array is not supported when the boot mode is configured to Legacy BIOS Mode.
Enabling Dynamic Smart Array RAID results in data loss or data corruption on existing SATA drives.
Back up all drives before enabling this option.
See your operating system documentation before enabling SATA AHCI support to ensure your base media drivers support this feature.

HPE Smart Array S100i SR Gen10 SW RAID does not support legacy boot mode.

you can refer to HPE Smart Array SR Gen10
Configuration Guide
http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/ha8000v/hard/Gen10/UEFI/881334-004_en.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I will try next week as soon as I will go to datacenter. I prefer not to use HPE Smart Array, I am using software raid and booting from drive(s). Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, I suggest you to use UEFI for thease reasons:
1. UEFI enables users to handle drives that are larger than 2 TB, while the old legacy BIOS couldn't handle large storage drives.
2. UEFI supports more than 4 primary partitions with a GUID Partition Table.
3. Computers UEFI firmware have faster booting process than the BIOS. Various optimizations and enhancement
4. UEFI supports secure startup, which means that the validity of the operating system can be checked to ensure that no malware tampers with the startup process.

Then do as you see fit

You can mark as solved

Comment: it helped! Thanks so much!